# div that is in fixed position at the bottom goes outside webpage

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a button that is always at the bottom and is sticky (fixed).

```
<div class="bg-red-200 fixed bottom-0 w-full">
```

However, the issue is that the div is not 100% width, but goes completely outside webpage, how can I fix that?

https://play.tailwindcss.com/7hDCAKujYQ

[image]

Comment: Should the button overflow the right sidebar?

Comment: @Dhaifallah no, it should just be within its parent div, where the content squares are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sticky` and `bottom-0` for the parent `div` of the `button` take a look [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/pFpeiLZa7X)

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="mx-auto flex h-max min-h-full w-full max-w-6xl">
  <div class="hidden sm:flex bg-red-400 w-1/3">left sidebar</div>
  <div class="flex relative flex-col w-96 space-y-4 ">
    <div class="mx-auto h-40 w-40 rounded-lg bg-black/10 backdrop-blur-sm">content</div>
    <div class="mx-auto h-40 w-40 rounded-lg bg-black/10 backdrop-blur-sm">content</div>
    <div class="mx-auto h-40 w-40 rounded-lg bg-black/10 backdrop-blur-sm">content</div>
    <div class="mx-auto h-40 w-40 rounded-lg bg-black/10 backdrop-blur-sm">content</div>
    <div class="mx-auto h-40 w-40 rounded-lg bg-black/10 backdrop-blur-sm">content</div>
    <div class="mx-auto h-40 w-40 rounded-lg bg-black/10 backdrop-blur-sm">content</div>
    <div class="mx-auto h-40 w-40 rounded-lg bg-black/10 backdrop-blur-sm">content</div>
    <div class="mx-auto h-40 w-40 rounded-lg bg-black/10 backdrop-blur-sm">content</div>
    <div class="mx-auto h-40 w-40 rounded-lg bg-black/10 backdrop-blur-sm">content last</div>
    
    <div class="sticky bottom-0  w-full bg-red-200">
      <button class="my-4 flex w-full justify-center rounded-md border border-blue-400 bg-blue-400 p-2 font-semibold text-white">Go Button</button>
    </div>
  
    </div>
  <div class="hidden lg:flex w-1/3 bg-green-400">right sidebar</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your html structure is not adjusted for wanted behavior. If you get you div with button outside of flex div, you can achieve this:

```
  <div class="flex flex-col w-96 relative">
    <div class="mx-auto h-40 w-40 rounded-lg bg-black/10 backdrop-blur-sm">content</div>
    <div class="mx-auto h-40 w-40 rounded-lg bg-black/10 backdrop-blur-sm">content</div>
    <div class="mx-auto h-40 w-40 rounded-lg bg-black/10 backdrop-blur-sm">content</div>
    <div class="mx-auto h-40 w-40 rounded-lg bg-black/10 backdrop-blur-sm">content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-red-200 fixed bottom-0 w-full">
    <button class="my-4 flex w-full justify-center rounded-md border border-blue-400 bg-blue-400 p-2 font-semibold text-white">Go button</button>
  </div>
```

You can check the result here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/71sRPrhRAE

Comment: Almost there, is just that I wanted to have this button to be full width of its parent div.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `left-0` to the div and it will work. as shown in link below

```
<div class="bg-red-200 fixed left-0 bottom-0 w-full">
```

***Edit:***

In this case u will need to add position `absolute` to ur button's div.

because `position: fixed` will add it relative to the screen.

```
<div class="bg-red-200 absolute w-full bottom-0 left-0">
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/71sRPrhRAE

***Edit 2:***

U should add `w-96` class to ur button div. as it has been added to the parent div
https://play.tailwindcss.com/7hDCAKujYQ

Comment: how can I make it full width of its parent (the middle div where I have the content)?

Comment: did u try adding `position: relative` to the parent div?

Comment: yes, I did, it didn't work. Also, that would mean that I had to use absolute, which cant be used with fixed?

Comment: I have edited the solution. hope it helps :)

Comment: that fixes the width issue, however the button is no longer in "fixed position", when there is more content the button gets pushed out of the screen

Comment: in that case, u should add `w-96` class to ur button div. as it has been added to the parent div

Comment: I see, it works in this case, however, what if the parent div has `w-full` as well?